# USER_AGENT headers for different browser versions

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-8, user-agent

I would like to run my website like previous versions by using the USER_AGENT. The reason is that I want to detect those old browsers in my site and show them a warning message.

At the moment I was doing this by using "Modify_headers" in firefox.

Is there any place with a list of all or at least the common user_agents used for Internet explorer / firefox ? (basically what I need is I.E 8.1 as this one is causing me problems)

If there is no any list, at least I would need the Internet Explorer 8.1 user agent.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as IE 8.1.

Comment: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php first result when using Google!

Comment: What is it about IE8 that doesn't work? Why don't you try detecting that specific feature using a tool like Modernizr, or polyfilling it?

Answer (score 1):

First you really do not want to do browser detection, feature detection first.

With that, I think you mean IE 11 on Windows 8.1, which tries to disguise itself to make it harder for folks to browser detect and therefor fallback to IE7 version, thus hurting the user by disabling all the new features IE has to offer.

My strategy for obsolete browsers is to serve them a plain vanilla page with no JavaScript and just some basic CSS to format the layout. No need to go out of your way for them, they can't handle new stuff that was not even created back in 2007-09. It saves you dev time but gives them something they can at least read and do basic interactions. So I do this on the server. Its still the same content, just not as sexy or interactive. You will probably still want to include an HTML5 shiv if you use any of the semantic tags so you can style them.

Other than that you should absolutely do nothing different for IE10/11 than you do for Chrome, well use prefixless CSS ;) If it works in Chrome its probably going to work in IE unless you make it not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how set header for each browser but we can detect browser type and its version too using Java Script..

```
window.navigator
```

Full code is:

```
 <script>
txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent language: " + navigator.systemLanguage + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>
```